# Custom Form Creation derived from Container Control

Tags: forms, winforms

### Visual C# 2015

1. I am trying to create a custom form inherited from containerControl.

   ```
   [
    Designer("MYService.Design.BFormRootDesigner", typeof(IRootDesigner))
   ]
   public class BFormEx : ContainerControl
   { }
   ```

   BFormRootDesigner is a separate class file derived from DocumentDesigner
2. I am able to open my form in the design mode.

   public partial class Form1 : BFormEx
   { }
3. But it is not showing at run time

Form1 Myform = new Form1();
Myform.Show();

Any solution.

Comment: You still need a **Form** to host that `ContainerControl` to show up. Add new `Form`, drop a `BFormEx` from the ToolBox, and `Application.Run(new TheNewForm());`. Or by code, create a new `Form` and new `BFormEx`, add it to the `From.Controls` collection, and show the **Form**.

Comment: i added the form it is mentioned in the s#2, #3                                                                          
public partial class Form1 : BFormEx { }
Form1 Myform = new Form1(); Myform.Show();

Comment: `BFormEx` is not a **Form**!

Comment: BFormEx is a Form. (similar to system,windows.forms.Form  which is derived from ContainerControl).   BFormEx is also derived from containercontrol

Now it is opening the form at run time.  
And  opens in Designer as well.   However another issue is that the formborder and control box are not drawn at design time. 
Any suggestion/solution ?.....

Comment: MyForm is opened by adding the following function.
Form look and style is based on the createparms     

       new internal void Show()
                {
                    SetTopLevel(true);
                    
                    //base.Show();
                }

Now another issue from DocumentDesigner(BFormRootDesigner). Unable to set form's styles(border, controlbox etc..) while opening the form at design time. 
What is to be done in DocumentDesigner ?.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code. Just inheriting the `ContainerControl` does not make it a `Form`. [This](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,71d66965280a3f7b) does. Does the `BFormEx` have something similar? We need to see the **CODE**. Otherwise it'll be a guess game.